# Call In/For a New Job

Tags: word-choice, expressions, prepositional-phrases

Suppose I looked for a job on the Internet, found a few offers interesting and decided to call the phone numbers they had posted. Am I *calling **in*** or *calling **for*** the new jobs? (Or should I simply say I'm "calling the new jobs"?)

And if I get a call from them and someone who's with me asks me who it is,
should I say my *work*, my *job*, or the caller's name and leave it at that?

Comment: You care calling "about a job listing", or "about a job opening", or simply "about a job".

Comment: I hope you are not talking about being currently employed, and gettin a call back AT YOUR WORKPLACE.  If so, make any excuse to get off the phone immediately, then make up a lie if anyone around you asks who called!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling an employer. You would say:

> I am calling an employer about a new job.

When you are called and asked your example question, you would say:

> Your peer: Who is it?
>   You: It's an employer who has a new job posting for which I applied.

..or any number of other responses to *"Who is it?"*:

> It's Jane from accounting.
>   It's someone from a company to which I applied.
>   It's a recruiter with information on a new job.
>   It's my friend Sally.
>   I'm not sure; I think it's a wrong number.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>*(or if you'd prefer to use conversational English to talk to your peer)*</sup>
>   It's a company that I applied to.
>   It's someone calling about my job application.
>   Just a company that wants to give me money.
>   Oh, I applied to a job posting a while back at this company and they're calling me back now.

Comment: Or (in everyday English) "It's the people I applied to for a job".

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but half of your answer is not what I would call idiomatic English.  It's really wordy and awkward.

Comment: Why would I write in idioms?

Answer (score 1):

Neither.  You are calling ***about*** or ***in reference to*** the new job.

> I'm calling *in reference to* the new job posting.

Your second question is more appropriate over at [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To call in a new job is to let someone know that there is a job for them to do (a new landscaping contract, for example). If you are talking to the potential employer, I'd recommend "I'm Frank Garrett and I'm calling to apply for position X which you posted on Thursday." If you are at your old job, someone calls about a new job, and a coworker asks who called, maybe just say "Simon at Better Company."